# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'convertGermanToBoolean.properties'

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, compiler-errors

When I Build my app I get the error: More than one file was found with OS independent path 'convertGermanToBoolean.properties'.

Additional Information:
I installed opencsv-5.0 library and created a libs folder for it.
Any insight on this error would be much appreciated.

Here is my my build.gradle file

```
ext {
    var = 29
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion var
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sae.iit.saedashboard"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.Paroca72:sc-gauges:3.5.3'
    implementation 'pl.pawelkleczkowski.customgauge:CustomGauge:1.0.4'
    //implementation project(':library-release')
    implementation files('C:/Users/SSalu/AndroidStudioProjects/SAE Dashboard (Merged) 7/library/opencsv-5.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/opencsv-5.0.jar')
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar', '*.jar'], exclude: [])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must delete `implementation files('libs/opencsv-5.0.jar')`  code
 because you already implement there :

```
implementation files('C:/Users/SSalu/AndroidStudioProjects/SAE Dashboard (Merged) 7/library/opencsv-5.0.jar')
```